# Eisenstein series and 163?

Tags: eisenstein-series, modular-forms, nt.number-theory

Given $q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and the Eisenstein series $E_{2k}(\tau)$, i.e.,

$$E_2(\tau) = 1-24\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n q^n}{1-q^n}$$

$$E_4(\tau) = 1+240\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^3 q^n}{1-q^n}$$

and so on. Define the function,

$$F_{2k}(\tau) = \frac{E_{2k}(\tau)}{\left(E_2(\tau)-\frac{3}{\pi\; \Im(\tau)}\right)^k}$$

for $k \geq 2$, where $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{-d}}{2}$, $\Im(\tau)$ is the imaginary part of $\tau$, and $d$ has class number $h(-d) = m$. For example, we have,

$$F_4\left(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2}\right) = \frac{5\cdot23\cdot29\cdot163}{2^2\cdot3\cdot181^2}$$

$$F_6\left(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-163}}{2}\right) = \frac{7\cdot11\cdot19\cdot127\cdot163^2}{2^9\cdot181^3}$$

$$F_8(\tau) = F_4^2(\tau)$$

and so on.

**Question**: In general, is it true that for $k \geq 2$ the function $F_{2k}$, ***like the j-function, is an algebraic number of degree m = h(-d)***?  (I've tested it with *d* with higher class numbers, and it seems to be true.)

Comment: Just a remark: I suspect knowing your conjecture for $k =2$ and $k = 3$ would imply it for all $k$, since one can express $E_{2k}$ in terms of $E_4$ and $E_6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I inadvertently came across the partial answer to my own question. It turns out Ramanujan had already explored something similar. Let $q = e^{2\pi i \tau}$, $\tau=\tfrac{1+\sqrt{-n}}{2}$, and,

$$P_n = 1-24\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k q^k}{1-q^k}$$

$$Q_n = 1+240\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^3 q^k}{1-q^k}$$

$$R_n = 1-504\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^5 q^k}{1-q^k}$$

$$a_n = \frac{b_n}{6} \left(1-\frac{Q_n}{R_n}\left(P_n-\frac{6}{\pi\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)$$

$$b_n = \sqrt{n(1728-j(\tau))}$$

and *[j-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html)* $j(\tau)$, then,

$$\frac{1}{F_4(\tau)} = \frac{1}{Q_n}\left(P_n-\frac{6}{\pi\sqrt{n}}\right)^2 = \left(1-\frac{6\,a_n}{b_n}\right)^2\left(\frac{-1728+j(\tau)}{j(\tau)}\right)$$

which is ***Theorem 7.1*** (p.13) of Berndt's "*[Ramanujan's contributions to Eisenstein Series](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.115.2404&rep=rep1&type=pdf)*".

Thus, it remains to establish that the square factor of the *RHS* is an algebraic number with the same degree as $j(\tau)$. (It seems it suffices to prove it for $a_n$.)

P.S. Note that for $n>3$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(6k)!}{(3k)!(k!)^3}\frac{a_n+b_n k}{(-j(\tau))^{k+1/2}} = \frac{1}{\pi}$$

in particular, for $n=163$, we have the Chudnovsky's formula,

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{(6k)!}{(3k)!(k!)^3}\frac{163096908+6541681608 k}{(640320^3)^{k+1/2}} = \frac{1}{\pi}$$

Comment: Nice. Just a quick question: why do P, Q and R have a subscript n?

Comment: @Vincent: Since their argument is $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt{\color{blue}{-n}}}{2}$.

Comment: you mentioned that it remains to establish that $a_n$ is an algebraic number with the same degree as $j(\tau)$. Do you have any ideas how one could prove that?